# Cargar archivos excel descartando los archivos dañados

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import functools
import xlrd
import io
import glob

HC01 = pd.concat(map(functools.partial(pd.read_excel, header=0, index_col=False),
                     glob.glob("E:\\prueba/*.xlsx")))
```

En el anterior script tengo el inconveniente de que cuando llamo a mis archivos de prueba genera un error

> `BadZipFile: Bad magic number for central directory`

Investigué y descubrí que en mis archivos hay muchos que están dañados, así que intenté llamar la hoja para que cargue `sheet_name = "Sheet"` solo los que tendrían esta hoja, pero no funciona:

```
HC01 = pd.concat(map(functools.partial(pd.read_excel, header=0, index_col=False, file_with_data, sheet_name = "Sheet"),
                     glob.glob("E:\\prueba/*.xlsx")))
```

¿Cómo cargar esos archivos excepto los dañados?

Comment: Usa un [try-except](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) que capture ese error, avise de éste con un print y, como realmente no se dio la excepción, seguirá con el siguiente archivo.

Comment: y alguna forma de detectarlos y eliminarlos?

Comment: Pueees, la misma tecnica: intentas cargarlos, y si falla los eliminas con, por ejemplo, os.remove